# Excel Table data changing rows on source refresh

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel table with data mixed from linked external data and user entered data.  The left most fields are pulled in from a Query (a saved view) on an SQL Server.  when the data comes in it is always in the same order.  The user can then add information to the rightmost fields

The problem that I am having is that upon refreshing the table, the user entered data will change the row that it was on.

Example:

```
PO number   UserField
XYZ1        will ship on time
ABC2        weekend OT required
STU3        (blank)
XYZ2        (blank)
```

---

after refresh

```
PO number     UserField
XYZ1          will ship on time
ABC2          (blank)
STU3          (blank)
XYZ2          weekend OT required
```

---

The row changes are not consistent -- subsequent changes may move the blank rows to different places.  I have also filled in data in every line and it will still shift.  The SQL sourced data does not change rows, only the user entered data.

is there a way to keep the user entered data connected to the SQL served data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how common this will be but it seems like we found the answer.  The problem stemmed from the queries updating very quickly.  Not sure why that got things out of sync, but it did. We changed the query properties to not allow background refresh -- forcing each query to finish before moving on.  This fixed the problem, 20+ refreshes and the user data has not moved again.